# Change language param code in URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I have changed my language code in URL from 3 to 2.So I want to redirect any old url to the new url through .htaccess

Example : I want to change the URL -

1) http://example.com/eng/News to http://example.com/en/News

2) http://example.com/deu/News to http://example.com/de/News

I am using CakePHP and this is the default .htaccess

```
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
     RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I tried using this :

```
      RewriteRule     (.*)/deu/(.*) $1/de/$2 [L]
```

But it didn't work.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the URL examples you should use the following directives:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/eng
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /en/$2 [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/deu
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /de/$2 [R]
```

The first RewriteCond directive will check whether the URI starts from /eng. If yes, the corresponding RewriteRule will replace "eng" with "en" and append the rest of the URI, which is available in the parameter $2. The R flag will initiate a redirect so that the new URL will be visible in the browser. Similarly for deu.

Comment: `  It didn't worked



    RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
  
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/eng
   RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /en/$2 [R]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`



   Can you please help .

Comment: Use this: 
`RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/eng
 RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /en/$2 [R]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/deu
 RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /de/$2 [R]`